# Ansible uri module send return to specific socket port

Tags: curl, ansible, proxy, socks

Setup:

Laptop -------------- Jumpserver ---------------- NetworkingDevice

I need to connect to the networkingdevice through a tunnel i open up between the laptop and jumpserver.

I can use the Ansible Proxycommand to setup this tunnel and it works fine for ssh - cli modules.

```
$ cat hosts
host vars:
[T1:vars]
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q abc@Jumpserver"'

$ ansible-proxy-test gtamilse$ ansible-playbook vmanage_cli.yml 
PLAY [Version Check] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check vManage version] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vManage302]
ok: [vManage301]

TASK [print output] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vManage302] => {
    "OUTPUT.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "20.4.1.2"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [vManage301] => {
    "OUTPUT.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "20.4.1.2"
        ]
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
vManage301                 : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vManage302                 : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

However this option does not help for http requests performed via uri module. (kinda makes sense since its a different protocol here - http)

```
$ansible-proxy-test gtamilse$ ansible-playbook vmanage_monitor.yml -vvv

TASK [Get Cookie] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/abc/Downloads/GITHUB/ansible-proxy-test/get-token.yml:19
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: abc
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~gtamilse && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132="` echo /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/modules/net_tools/basics/uri.py
<localhost> PUT /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23894nx1jksbl/tmp137_uyxg TO /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132/AnsiballZ_uri.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132/ /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132/AnsiballZ_uri.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132/AnsiballZ_uri.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1643818240.140169-23908-100428296780132/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
FAILED - RETRYING: Get Cookie (60 retries left).Result was: {
    "attempts": 1,
    "changed": false,
    "content": "",
    "elapsed": 30,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "body": {
                "j_password": "abc",
                "j_username": "abc"
            },
            "body_format": "form-urlencoded",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "creates": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "POST",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": true,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                200
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "https://networkingdeviceip/dataservice/j_security_check",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error timed out>",
    "redirected": false,
    "retries": 61,
    "status": -1,
    "url": "https://networkingdeviceip/dataservice/j_security_check"
}
```

Ansible URI code:

```
- name: Get Cookie
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_host }}/dataservice/j_security_check"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    body:
      j_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      j_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: no
  #no_log: True
  register: login_results
  delegate_to: localhost
  until: login_results.set_cookie is defined
  when: (viptela_api_cookie is not defined) or (login_results.msg is not search('OK'))
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
  until: login_results is not failed
```

I have tried setting up the tunnel outside of ansible and running the same request using curl with proxy and it works. So it can be done but need help to understand how to do it in ansible with uri module.

```
$ ssh -D 8222 -N -f abc@Jumpserver
 
$ ps -A | grep ssh
 2506 ??         0:00.13 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
56884 ??         0:00.04 ssh -D 8222 -N -f abc@Jumpserver
60374 ttys004    0:00.00 grep ssh
36516 ttys008    0:00.53 ssh jumpserver
 
$ curl -x socks5h://localhost:8222 -k -v --request POST 'https://networkingdeviceip/j_security_check' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'j_username=abc' --data-urlencode 'j_password=abc'

*   Trying ::1:8222...
* SOCKS5 connect to networkingdeviceip (remotely resolved)
* SOCKS5 request granted.
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8222 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> POST /j_security_check HTTP/1.1
> Host: networkingdeviceip:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 33
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< set-cookie: JSESSIONID=XpqHiwHGXebaMZkl3MK03i9erR3Vo1Q009ZcvqD9.28e897a8-2ddc-4e3e-b126-9c7a36fba981; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< pragma: no-cache
< x-frame-options: DENY
< date: Wed, 02 Feb 2022 03:09:13 GMT
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< content-length: 0
< server: svcproxy
```

Any suggestions on how make this work with ansible uri module, whereby we can set the request return to a specific port. Looking for the equivalent of curl -x (proxy) socks5h://localhost:8222 in ansible

Comment: Hi gowthamt welcome to SO. [The fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) indicates that ansible supports the same proxy environment variables as python does, so `environment: { https_proxy: "socks5h://localhost:8222" }` either on that task or in the playbook is likely what you want, although from some quick searching it seems `socks5h:` requires pysocks5, so ensure the **remote** python interpreter has that library available to it. Good luck!

Comment: I also just spotted the `delegate_to: localhost` in your task; that may just be flailing trying to get it to work, but I sincerely doubt that's what you really want to happen, as it will cause the `uri:` to execute on your _control node_, not "networking device"

Comment: Hi mdaniel! thanks for the response!
I tried your suggestion of adding the environment proxy and setting it to the task, along with install pysocks5 on the jumpserver. 

But still no luck, i tried multiple variations of this - turning on/off delegate_to localhost

```
$ cat global-variables.yml 
proxy_env:
  https_proxy: "socks://localhost:8222"

- name: Get Cookie
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_host }}/dataservice/j_security_check"
    method: POST
    #use_proxy: false
  #delegate_to: localhost
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}" 
```

Comment: Notice one more thing when i set delegate_to localhost off, it looks like the connection request reaches the networkingdevice (vmanage302) but the server closes the connection...(but this works fine when done with curl)
pasted the output on next comment

Comment: "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Connection failure: connection was closed before a valid response was received: No status line received - the server has closed the connection",
    "redirected": false,
    "url": "https://ip/dataservice/j_security_check",
    "warnings": [
        "Platform darwin on host vManage302 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information."
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

Solution - run playbook with delegate_to set as the Jumpserver not localhost, and turn off connection:local setting at the task and play level.

This did the trick and I didnt need the ssh tunnel (ssh -D) that was setup earlier. With this method, it's all done via remote execution.

Pre-req - ensure the ssh key exchange is done between localmachine and jumpserver so you can authenticate without passwords.

SSH Remote execution works with Proxycommand set in vars/host file:

```
[T1:vars]
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q abc@jumpserver"'
```

HTTP Remote Execution work by delegating execution to remote host and turning off connection: local

```
- name: Get Cookie
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_host }}/dataservice/j_security_check"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: no
    #use_proxy: false
  register: login_results
  delegate_to: <jumpserverip>
  #delegate_to: localhost
  #connection: local
```